# what is the actual story of Maa Kali ending Raktabheej?

Tags: shiva, kali

I have heard many versions of it, but this one stuck with me. Did maa kali behead Lord Shiva when he stepped down to calm her? And his head went spinning out of the universe and when kali gained consciousness she took the roop of parvati and went to get shiva's head and hugged his head which took the shape of Yoni(almost like a circle surrounding the shivling). please correct me if I am wrong and give further insights.

Comment: Actually no. Lord Shiva is not related to Raktabeeja Vadha.

Answer (score 1):

The most authoritative text for Shaktas is **Devi Mahatmya** (also known as Durga Saptashati or Sri Sri Chandi) is part of Markandeya Mahapurana. Devi Mahatmya has an entire chapter (chapter 8) on the killing of Raktaveeja. Here I am quoting the relevant part from that chapter.

Whatever you wrote noting is mentioned there. This is what happened -

> By the stream of blood, which fell on the earth from him when he received many wounds from the spears, darts and other weapons, Asuras came verily into being in hundreds. And those Asuras who sprang from that Asura’s blood pervaded the whole world; thereat the gods fell into the utmost terror. Seeing the gods dejected, **Caṇḍika spoke with haste; she said to Kālī, “O Cāmuṇḍā! stretch out thy mouth wide; with this mouth do thou quickly take in the great Asuras, which are the drops of blood, that have come into being out of Raktavīja at the descent of my weapon on him**. Roam about in the battle, devouring the great Asuras who sprang from him; so shall this Daitya with his blood ebbing away meet destruction. These fierce demons are being devoured by thee and at the same time no others will be produced.”

> Having enjoined her thus, the goddess next smote him with her dart. **Kālī swallowed Raktavīja’s blood with her mouth. Then he struck Caṇḍikā with his club there; and the blow of his club caused her no pain, even the slightest, but from his stricken body blood flowed copiously, and from whatever direction it came, Cāmuṇḍā takes it then with her mouth. The great Asuras, who sprang up from the flow of blood in her mouth, Cāmuṇḍā both devoured them and quaffed his blood. The goddess smote Raktavīja with her dart, her thunder-bolt, arrows, swords and spears, when Cāmuṇḍā drank up his blood. Stricken with that multitude of weapons, he fell on the earth’s surface, and the great Asura Raktavīja became blood-less, O king.** Thereat the thirty gods gained joy unparalleled, O king. The band of Mothers which sprang from them broke into a dance, being intoxicated with blood.

So, from the above, Lord Shiva is not involved during Kali's combat against Raktabija.

That is it, and that is all.

Reference -

1. [Sri Sri Chandi translated by Frederick Eden Pargiter](https://saraswat-prakashan.weebly.com/srisri-chandi.html)

Comment: Thankyou. Can i find this text in mahapurans too?

Comment: @Anushka Yes, as I mentioned this is part of Markandeya Mahapurana. If I am not wrong chapter 81 to 93 are Devi Mahatmya. So the 8th chapter means most probably chapter 88 of Markandeya Purana.

Comment: @Anushka If you find the answer useful, you may upvote and accept it as the right answer.